# Creating associative array from linear array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a web service that returns JSON data, which, when I decode with PHP's [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, gives me an array like the following:

```
Array
(
 [0] => eBook
 [1] => 27
 [2] => Trade Paperback
 [3] => 24
 [4] => Hardcover
 [5] => 4
)
```

Is there a PHP function that will take this array and combine it into an associative array where every other element is a key and the following element is its value? What I want to come up with is the following:

```
Array
(
 [eBook] => 27
 [Trade Paperback] => 24
 [Hardcover] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own solution is clearer for sure, but this one-liner, made of PHP functions only, does the same job:

```
$output = call_user_func_array('array_combine', call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge(array(null), array_chunk($input, 2))));
```

Your question was "is there a PHP function...". The answer is no, but for a combination thereof it is yes.

The tricky part here is the transposition of the chunked array, which is achieved by calling `array_map` with `null` as the first argument (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) where it says "an interesting use of this function...")

Comment: I like that. I'd definitely opt for this code (plus some good documentation so that everyone other contributors don't have to scratch their heads)

Comment: ...but you have already opted for another code. The documentation is all in the PHP manual, except for the matrix transposition trick that is a bit hidden.

Comment: No problem. I had accepted the other answer before you posted your question. They are both _great_ answers, but I think that yours adds more to the discussion (which is what SO is all about, right?)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no built-in function that does this, but you could use a function like the following:

```
function combineLinearArray( $arrayToSmush, $evenItemIsKey = true ) {
    if ( ( count($arrayToSmush) % 2 ) !== 0 ) {
        throw new Exception( "This array cannot be combined because it has an odd number of values" );
    }

    $evens = $odds = array();

    // Separate even and odd values
    for ($i = 0, $c = count($arrayToSmush); $i < $c; $i += 2) {
        $evens[] = $arrayToSmush[$i];
        $odds[] = $arrayToSmush[$i+1];
    }

    // Combine them and return
    return ( $evenItemIsKey ) ? array_combine($evens, $odds) : array_combine($odds, $evens);
}
```

You can call that with the array you want to combine into an associative array and and optional flag indicating whether to use even or odd elements as the keys.

**Edit:** I changed the code to use only one for loop, rather than a separate loop to extract even and odd values.

Comment: If you knew the answer why ask it?

Comment: stackoverflow encourages that sort of knowledge-sharing: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ Since there is no function that does this in PHP's library, I wanted to make it available to people who may be searching for a solution to this sort of problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey , please notice the timestamps of question and answer

Comment: @tereško So?  Instant self-answers are now *officially condoned.*  Read the meta post I linked.

Answer (score 1):

A loop like this could work:

```
$array = json_decode(....);

$received = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $received[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
    $i++;
}

var_dump($received);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd suggest, except why <= on count -1?

Comment: Because count will start counting at 1, but your arrays' key starts at 0.

Comment: If you didn't add the -1, you'd have an empty array key/value at the end of your array.

Comment: Drop the <=, make it <, and remove the -1, if the count were 3, you're telling it to loop until less than or equal to 2, where you could have just said, less than 3 (which is 2)

Comment: @sixeightzero: Maybe thats why we have '<' operator as well. :)

Comment: **please** don't use `sizeof()`. It's an alais and does nothing but make it harder to read. Use the proper function `count()`...

Comment: Do you expect the original array to change? If no, then why are you re-counting it all the time. And the way you iterate is just confusing: `for( $i = 0; $i < $max ; $i+=2 )` would be much cleaner.

Comment: @tereško correct, but we don't know the size of the array or if/when it will change. To prevent the need to keep changing `$max`, just do a count. It is not a costly function.

Answer (score 1):

Adjustment to the code in the other answer:

```
function combineLinearArray( $arrayToSmush) {

if ( ( count($arrayToSmush) % 2 ) !== 0 ) {
    throw new Exception( "This array cannot be combined because it has an odd number of values" );
}

$combined = array();
for ($i = 0, $i<count($arrayToSmush); $i++) {
    $combined[$arrayToSmush[$i]] = $arrayToSmush[$i+1];
    $i++; // next key
}

// Combine them and return
return $combined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of 1-liners:

```
array_reduce(array_chunk($input, 2), function(&$r, $i) { !empty($i[0]) && $r[$i[0]] = @$i[1]; return $r; }, array());
```

This 1-liner also verifies the immediate validity of the resulting assoc key and is 10 or so chars shorter than the accepted one https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265111/1990515